# The Euler-Cauchy differential equation from a given basis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the Euler-Cauchy differential equation with solutions $y_1=x^{3}$ and $y_2=0$?

The general solution should be in the form $C_1x^{m_1}+C_2x^{m_2}$ where $m_1$or $m_2$ is $3$ but how does $0$ fit here?

Comment: Any homogeneous linear equation **always** has the trivial solution $0$. It is not considered a fundamental solution.

Comment: You obtain $0$ when $C_1 = C_2 = 0$.

Comment: In general you construct the characteristic polynomial from the powers of the basis and then transform it into the Newton interpolation form at the node points $0,1,2,...$. Here, assuming $y_2=1=x^0$, you would get $(r-0)(r-3)=r((r-1)-2)$ leading to $x^2y''-2xy'=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this equation is $y\cdot\left(y'-3x^2\right)=0$ or $y\cdot\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-3x^2\right)=0$.